# 1.9.1 Responsive Transactional Emails: totals break table

Tags: template, email-templates, ce-1.9.1.0, rwd, transactional

I'm upgrading to 1.9.1 and I'm embracing the RWD email templates. Where are the totals generated for the transactional emails?  The order totals are breaking the table (see image). I can't find what's building getChildHtml('order_totals')

It's not /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/email/order/totals/wrapper.phtml

And it's not /app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/email/order/items/order/default.phtml

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

[image: example]

Comment: So how can I fix this, I had the same issue after upgrading. ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jLo1p.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it. The email totals are created by  /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/sales/order/totals.phtml

Answer (score 0):

\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout\sales.xml

in the RWD theme files is also important which contains a section called:

Email layouts section

which contains the template path to the wrapper.phtml file mentioned in the initial question.

email/order/totals/wrapper.phtml

Make sure you empty and refresh your cache if you upload the sales.xml file to your own theme (\app\design\frontend\xxxxx\default\layout\sales.xml) if you don't already have a sales.xml file which worked for me in addition to adding the files in the following RWD template folders to my own theme (eg. \app\design\frontend\xxxxx\default\template):

\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\email

\app\design\frontend\rwd\default\template\sales